# Python Class variable initialization access variables out side init

Tags: python, django, django-forms, python-2.7

I'm using Django for our project. And I have created a form using Django forms. In one of the form i need to check a variable and based on the value of the variable i need to add or remove an element.

I'm passing this variable to the form when the object is initialized.
ie `form=MyForm(flag)`

And in the forms class i'm doing this

```
class MyInfoForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args,**kwargs):
        self.flag= kwargs.pop('flag', None)
        super(MyInfoForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        print self.flag

    Firstname = forms.CharField(label=u' First name :', max_length=30)
```

In the init function i have printed the flag and its working fine. But how can i access the variable out side *init*
I tried

```
    class MyInfoForm(forms.Form):
        myFlag=None
        def __init__(self, *args,**kwargs):
            self.flag= kwargs.pop('flag', None)
            myFlag=self.flag
            super(MyInfoForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            print self.flag

        Firstname = forms.CharField(label=u' First name :', max_length=30)
        print myFlag
```

But its not working.

Comment: Check your indentation in the second example.

Comment: @Daniel I have corrected this. Actually it this might happened when i copy and pasted the code....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `class` statement is an executable statement that:

1. creates a namespaces
2. execute, sequentially, all code at the top-level of the class statement block
3. call the appropriate metaclass (defaulting to `type`) with the classname, namespace, and list of parent classes
4. bind the newly created `class` object to the classname in the enclosing (usually the module) namespace

To make a long story short you just cannot access instance attributes from within the `class` statement body, since neither the instance nor even the class itself exist yet.

If what you want is to update / add / remove fields on a per instance basis and according to some argument passed to the form's initializer, the correct solution is to first call the parent's initializer (to make sure your form's instance fields are correctly initialized) then do whatever you have to do, ie:

```
class MyInfoForm(forms.Form):
    firstname = forms.CharField(label=u' First name :', max_length=30)
    def __init__(self, *args,**kwargs):
        self.flag= kwargs.pop('flag', None)
        super(MyInfoForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.flag:
            # XXX IMPORTANT : 
            # you want to access self.fields['fieldname']                
            # NOT self.fieldname
            self.fields["firstname"].label = "Yadda"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print MyInfoForm.myFlag
```

how abou this?

Answer (score 0):

This depends... should the scope of flag be the class, or the instance of the class?

If the scope should be the instance (this is what it seems like from your first try), then you access it by doing:

```
instance = MyInfoForm(flag)
...
instance.flag
```

If, on the other hand, the variable flag belongs to the class (meaning, there is only one value for flag for every instance of MyInfoForm), then you can access it by doing:

```
MyInfoForm.myFlag #using your second attempt
```

Also... You're declaring the variable as `myFlag`, and trying to print `myflag`. Variable names are case sensitive.

Comment: Sorry there was an indentation error in my second example. I want to access the value of myFlag just after the init function. I aim is to initialize the variable myFlag through init and use it later.